# Teradata does it have a ROLLBACK

Tags: teradata, rollback

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    DELETE FROM DW_RX_V.RX_FLL_FCT
    WHERE rx_nbr  = IN_RX_NBR   
    AND rx_fll_dte  = CAST(IN_RX_FLL_DTE AS TIMESTAMP(6) FORMAT 'MMDDYYYY')  
    AND rfl_tie_brk_nbr   = IN_RFL_TIE_BKR;

    IF :ACTIVITY_COUNT = 0
    THEN
    ROLLBACK;
    SIGNAL ERROR_HANDLER;

    END IF;


    DELETE from DW_RX_V.RX_FLL_DET
    WHERE rx_nbr = IN_RX_NBR   
    AND rx_fll_dte  = CAST(IN_RX_FLL_DTE AS TIMESTAMP(6) FORMAT 'MMDDYYYY')  
    AND rfl_tie_brk_nbr   = IN_RFL_TIE_BKR;

    IF :ACTIVITY_COUNT = 0
    THEN
    ROLLBACK;
    SIGNAL ERROR_HANDLER;

    END IF;

END TRANSACTION;
```

I just tried using the stored procedure block above, upon running, it still not able to rollback the transaction upon failure.

Does Teradata really have a rollback?

So what I want is, everytime there is no record found on the second DML statement, then rollback everything what is deleted from the start.

Comment: How is the handler for `ERROR_HANDLER` defined? Should be `EXIT`, not `CONTINUE`. `ACTIVITY_COUNT ` is a builtin variable, so there's no `:`.

Comment: DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR ERROR_HANDLER
 BEGIN
    SET v_err_msg_txt= 'DELETE FAILED'
    ELSE NULL
        END ;
   IF v_msg IS NOT NULL
   THEN
   <SOME DML STATEMENT TO INSERT TO ERROR TABLE>
   END IF;
    <SOME PRINT STATEMENT>
    END;

Comment: That is how the ERROR_HANDLER defined, is there something wrong or missing with it?

Comment: There's no more `PRINT` in an SP, but otherwise this should work. What exactly happens when you run it? Btw, instead of checking for zero activity count you could also implement a `HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND` which is automatically activated when a DML doesn't find any rows.

Comment: Hi Thanks again for the reply. Yes, upon running, nothing happens, it eventually deletes the record even if the Rollback has been called. Our DBA said that rollback doesn't work in TD, so i'm quite confused right now.

Comment: you can have two BT - ET blocks. In the BT ET block all the dmls are treated as one single transaction. Are you sure that activity_count=0. Can you please assign the activity_count to a variable just to be sure once. Put the variable in the if condition. Put the two if conditions in two separate BT-ET blocks and then check once. @Gemudesu